# Find the secret word hidden in this message

Tags: word, cipher, computer-puzzle, letters

<sup>(*TL;DR at the bottom*)</sup>

The following message was received from a friend:

> I need you right away to help me use `0x1DD1A` to find out how to set up my `0x223C` `0x71C487`!

The message didn't make sense at first, so I went to him for clarification and he told me he just got an Echo Connect and needed help accessing Google so he could set it up. There's no way the message could've gotten encrypted like this without intention.

Can you figure out what 10-letter word he has hidden with his message?

---

$\text{TL;DR } {\small \text{ (i.e. same puzzle without the flavor text):}}$

$$\text{223C = Echo}$$
$$\text{71C487 = Connect}$$
$$\text{1DD1A = Google}$$

$$\text{What is the hidden 10-letter word?}$$

---

<sup>Disclaimer: This is a puzzle I made. No friends were actually involved.</sup>

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First step:

> Convert hexadecimal to decimal.
>  $$\text{0x223C}=8764=\text{Echo}$$
>  $$\text{0x71C487}=7455879=\text{Connect}$$
>  $$\text{0x1DD1A}=122138=\text{Google}$$

Second step:

> Each digit corresponds to a letter.
>
> ```
> 1 → G
> 2 → O
> 3 → L
> 4 → O
> 5 → N
> 6 → H
> 7 → C
> 8 → E
> 9 → T
> ```

Last step:

> Read the letters from 9 to 1 then it says **TECHNOLOG**.
>
>  There is no **0** in this puzzle, but its corresponding letter might be **Y**: so the answer is **TECHNOLOGY**.

Comment: That is correct!